# stylesheet child theme issue - woothemes canvas

Tags: wordpress, canvas, themes

I encountered a problem with my wordpress (canvas) site in ie8 and traced it to the stylesheet link in the header of my child theme - this code:

```
href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>"
```

translates in the browser as "...canvas-child/style.css" which is wrong - according to woothemes instructions you should customize css in your child theme with 'custom.css' only, and leave 'style.css' in your parent 'canvas' theme. I really need to know 1. is this an error 2. what should this php code be pointing to? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried changing the name to style.css instead? Naming the stylesheet style.css in your Child template won't do any harm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out: http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes for information on child themes.

*style.css is the one and only required file in a child theme. It provides the information header by which WordPress recognizes the child theme, and it replaces the style.css of the parent.*

When you use Child Templates, just copy a file with the same name to your child theme and enter your adjustments here.

Comment: thanks, I had to put in style.css in my child theme and also custom.css. Stupid of me.